# Is there a way to identify the cell selected in the parent uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to load different sets of data into a single uitableview dependent on which cell was selected in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method of the previous view.

What i would like to do is set a value inside the newly pushed view that can change the requests that I do to a php script of my choosing.

For instance if I could pass my newly pushed view a number I would have an if statement or maybe a switch, that switch statement would then make use of my ASIFormDataRequest wrapper I am usnig telling my request nsobject to execute the php script I have related to this cell selection, then pass the data-back.

I hope this makes sense, if you have any experience with what I am trying to achive and can see a better way of doing it I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property in the detail view controller that would be set from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. This assumes you have your data stored in an NSArray as a array of numbers. Your implementation will likely vary from this, but the idea is the same.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]];
    detailViewController.number = [self.mydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

If you wanted to, you could also create a custom init method to pass this information. In your init method, you would set the property from the parameter passed into it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNumber:[self.mydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Ahh, with respect to your section section of code, would **mydata** be declared in the deatilViewController as a NSInteger? or something else?

Comment: also, I thought when you initalized a new view like that you had to use the initWithNibName: if so would I just add the initWithNumber after that.

Comment: mydata could be anything really, it's an NSArray in my example.

Comment: your initWithNumber method would in turn call the initWithNibName:  It's common for initialize method to chain off one another like that

Comment: okay cool, dose order matter? should you always call initWithNibName after you have initialized values? or dose it not matter, also when I try to initWithNumber my intelisense dose not bring it up as an option.

Comment: Just looking through the developer site and I cannot find any reference to initWithNumber..